# How to resize a QLabel displayed by a QWidgetAction after changing it's text

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu

I use a `QWidgetAction` to add a header to a context menu (that will also show up on Windows, no matter what style is used, in contrast to `addSection()`, which does not always actually display the title).

The action's widget is a `QLabel`. It's text is changed by each invocation of the context menu. The menu is setup in the constructor of my class, and the `QWidgetAction` is added like so (all `m_` variables are member variables declared in the header):

```
m_contextMenu = new QMenu(this);
m_menuTitle = new QLabel;
m_menuTitle->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
m_menuTitle->setMargin(4);
QWidgetAction *titleAction = new QWidgetAction(m_contextMenu);
titleAction->setDefaultWidget(m_menuTitle);
m_contextMenu->addAction(titleAction);
m_contextMenu->addSeparator();
```

When the menu is requested, the text of the label is changed and the menu is displayed like so:

```
m_menuTitle->setText(tr("%1 „%2“").arg(some_variable, some_other_variable));
...
m_contextMenu->exec(place_to_display);
```

When the label's text is set for the first time (with a short text the label's text is set to), everything is fine:

[image]

but when it's set to some longer text, the size remains the same and the text is cropped:

[image]

I tried to fix this, but the only working solution I found was to define the `QAction`s displayed in the menu in the constructor, owned by `this`, setting the label's text, clearing the menu and adding the actions again, like so:

```
m_contextMenu->clear();

m_menuTitle->setText(tr("%1 „%2“").arg(some_variable, some_other_variable));

m_contextMenu->addAction(m_menuTitleAction);
m_contextMenu->addSeparator();
m_contextMenu->addAction(m_editAction);
m_contextMenu->addAction(m_deleteAction);

m_contextMenu->exec(place_to_display);
```

Is there a way to resize the title without rebuilding the menu each time?

Comment: QWidgetAction has no size. You need to reword the question? I would want to see more code for that.

Comment: I added the code of the menu setup and the menu invocation. It's about the width of the QLabel the QWidgetAction displays and the width of the QMenu which stays the same after the QLabel's text is set for the first time.

Comment: The answer is maybe a shot in the dark but similar solution worked for me once.

Comment: Maybe [QWidget::adjustSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#adjustSize) is what you need.

Comment: No, that was the first thing I tried …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to send a resize event instead:

```
m_menuTitle->setText(tr("%1 „%2“").arg(some_variable, some_other_variable));
...
QResizeEvent re(new_size, m_contextMenu->size());
qApp->sendEvent(m_contextMenu, &re);
```

This will set the QMenu's internal `itemsDirty` flag and will force geometry recalculation when the menu is shown. *Note that the new size in the event does not matter, as the menu will aways resize based on its `sizeHint()`!*

Comment: That's it! Thanks :-)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Would you be kind enough to explain what this hack does differently than `QWidget::adjustSize` and `QWidget::updateGeometry`? In my case the menu lives in a `QMenuBar` and it is hidden at the moment when the resize happens. I find the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#updateGeometry) not very clear, but I presume that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `QResizeEvent` solution didn't really work for me (with a more complex widget), I found the generic solution by reading the `QMenu` and `QAction` source code.

```
m_widget->installEventFilter(this);
// and in my case m_widget->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);

bool SomeClass::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    if (watched == m_widget && event->type() == QEvent::Resize) {
        // Force QMenu to recalculate the geometry of this item
        QActionEvent e(QEvent::ActionChanged, this);
        qApp->sendEvent(m_contextMenu, &e);
    }
    ...
}
```

`QActionEvent` triggers everything we need in `QMenu`: recalculating geometries, resizing the menu to its new size (if it's visible), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This answer extends [user362515's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728602/4248972).

There is little more effort required if you change the size of a hidden widget action (e.g., because of its menu is currently collapsed).
Create a new class `ActionWidget` which derives publicly from `QWidget`.
Then override the `showEvent` method and implement it like this:

```
void ActionWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent* event)
{
  QResizeEvent resize_event(QSize(), parentWidget()->size());

  parentWidget()->adjustSize();
  qApp->sendEvent(parentWidget(), &resize_event);

  QWidget::showEvent(event);
}
```

Notice that `adjustSize` must be called on the parent widget of the action widget and the event must be sent to the parent widget.

Of course, you must also reimplement `QWidgetAction::createWidget` such that it returns an instance of the `ActionWidget`-class and make sure that `ActionWidget` reports a proper (updated) size hint.